# Convert SQL data in HTML format to standard text in SSRS

Tags: html, sql, ssrs-2008, data-conversion

I have an MVC2 C#. Net web app that is storing data in html format for certain description fields.  When displaying the data using SSRS, the data is showing with the excaped html characters...ie.,

```
&lt;p&gt;&amp;quot;YOU KNOW WHAT IT MEANS TO ASSUME&amp;quot;&lt;/p&gt;
```

So it looks weird in the report.  I can do Nested REPLACEs on the text to create the correct output:

```
"YOU KNOW WHAT IT MEANS TO ASSUME"
```

But it seems like there should be some kind of built in functinin SQL that would do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you Google for "html ssrs"??

I found this page: [Displaying HTML content in Reporting Services 2008](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2008/08/25/displaying-html-content-in-reporting-services-2008.aspx)

Here are the steps:

1. In the table where I want to display the column, right-click the cell and chose Create Placeholder....
2. On the General tab (of the new placeholder's properties), set the value to the required column.
3. In the Markup type, choose the option for HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles

Comment: @Tony....I don't see the Create Placeholder menu item.  I'll check out the article

Comment: @MikeTWebb - To be fair I was not able to test what the article said (not on a machine with access to SSRS at the moment). I'll confirm tomorrow at work - unless you manage to sort it out before then! :)

Comment: @MikeTWebb - Interesting, I'll have to have a play with it when I can connect to SSRS again at work. I also have some books there which might help.

Answer (score 2):

regular expressions:

```
= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(StringWithHTMLtoStrip, "<[^>]+>","")
```

[Source](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2003/05/13/6963.aspx)

Another good example [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619174622/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042501-1.shtml)

Comment: @Diego.....System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex doesn't exist in my version of SSRS